# Unable to upgrade to pip 1.4.1 for Python2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I installed pip via easy_install but on checking pip version it still shows:

```
pip 1.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

This is how PIP installation took place:

```
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.4.1
Processing pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
pip 1.4.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
Installing pip-2.7 script to /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin

Using /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Python version collision, between the system Python on OSX and the one you installed. This can be resolved in several ways, but I highly recommend you reinstall Python via `Homebrew`. When installing Python with `Homebrew`, `pip` and `setup_tools` will also be installed as well and everything will be taken care of (you will not need to use `sudo` to install Python modules).

See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

You will save yourself many headaches using Homebrew to manage your Python distribution.

Comment: Will it overwirde Pythons installed via Macport and Apple one?

Comment: It will not overwrite the System Python and it shouldn't conflict with Macports. But I **HIGHLY** recommend you move away from Macports. The whole idea behind Homebrew is that programs are installed in '/usr/local/Cellar' (the Cellar) and it goes to great lengths to minimize collisions. It also never requires sudo to install programs.

Comment: If you want more info about my personal setup and my personal opinion as to why Homebrew is great, see my blogpost @ http://www.williamdenman.ca/blog-posts/2013/10/25_my-setup-osx-emacs-and-python-playing-nicely.html

Comment: I to recommend you use Homebrew installed versions of Python. However you may in fact find the solution to your problem in my answer, but it will become irrelevant once you start using Homewbrew :)

Comment: Ok I am d/l it. I don't want to keep so many Python versions so will prefer to unstall ports pertain Python

Comment: @WilliamDenman Brew doctor gives so many warnings.. http://justpaste.it/dudm  What should I do? I dont want brew mess with RVM I use for Rails

Comment: I don't see any mention of RVM in the output, so you should be fine. Go through each warning and fix according to the message, they are quite verbose. Most can be fixed by editing your PATH environment variable. Most of these warnings are caused by MacPorts messing around. Have you tried at least @JamesMills solution first?

Comment: Righ now these are my *.bash_profile* entries

*export  PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH*